# Was there an "expressionless" woman admitted to Cedar Senai hospital in LA in 1972?

Tags: history, healthcare

[The story goes](http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Expressionless):

> In June of 1972, a woman appeared in Cedar Senai hospital in nothing but a white, blood-covered gown. Now this, in itself, should not be too surprising as people often have accidents nearby and come to the nearest hospital for medical attention, but there were two things that caused people who saw her to vomit and flee in terror.
>   **The first being that she wasn't exactly human. she resembled something close to a mannequin, but had the dexterity and fluidity of a normal human being. Her face, was as flawless as a mannequins, devoid of eyebrows and smeared in make-up.**
>
> There was a kitten clamped in her jaws so unnaturally tight that no teeth could be seen, and the blood was still squirting out over her gown and onto the floor. She then pulled it out of her mouth, tossed it aside and collapsed.
>
> From the moment she stepped through the entrance to when she was taken to a hospital room and cleaned up before being prepped for sedation, she was completely calm, expressionless and motionless. The doctors thought it best to restrain her until the authorities could arrive and she did not protest. They were unable to get any kind of response from her and most staff members felt too uncomfortable to look directly at her for more than a few seconds.
>
> But the second the staff tried to sedate her, she fought back with extreme force. Two members of staff had to hold her down as her body rose up on the bed with that same, blank expression.
>
> She turned her emotionless eyes towards the male doctor and did something unusual. She smiled.
>
> As she did, the female doctor screamed and let go out of shock. In the woman's mouth were not human teeth, but long, sharp spikes. Too long for her mouth to close fully without causing any damage…
>
> The male doctor stared back at her for a moment before asking "What in the hell are you?"
>
> She cracked her neck down to her shoulder to observe him, still smiling.
>
> There was a long pause, the security had been alerted and could be heard coming down the hallway.
>
> As he heard them approach, she darted forward, sinking her teeth into the front of his throat, ripping out his jugular and letting him fall to the floor, gasping for air as he choked on his own blood.
>
> She stood up and leaned over him, her face coming dangerously close to his as the life faded from his eyes.
>
> She leaned closer and whispered in his ear.
>
> "I...am....God...."
>
> The doctor's eyes filled with fear as he watched her calmly walk away to greet the security men. His last ever sight would be watching her feast on them one by one.
>
> The female doctor who survived the incident named her "The Expressionless".
>
> **There was never a sighting of her again.**

This seems to be an urban legend, usually accompanied by the following photo:

[image: the expressionless woman]

Is there any evidence that any of the above actually occurred, and that the photo has any relation to a woman of the sort described in the story?

Comment: Could the real god stand up and debunk her, please?

Comment: You could maybe look up records in 1947 to see how many male doctors in the LA area died in June... or maybe homicides committed at the hospital during that time... but honestly, like most urban legends, there just isn't anything *concrete* here.

Comment: mhhh... this is [Creepypasta](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Creepypasta), written [by this guy](http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/User:Ivysir).

Comment: @Tacroy: 1947? Do you mean 1972? In any case, there ought to be corroborating newspaper stories or other reports by credible media outlets discussing this.

Comment: @Oliver_C: Is the fellow you linked to with respect to Creepypasta the original author of the story?

Comment: @Tacroy - Well, there is a [Cedars Sinai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedars-Sinai_Medical_Center) hospital which is close enough to the "Cedar Senai" that I can see how it might drift over time.

Comment: @Brian: [Ivysir](http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/User:Ivysir)'s page includes this statement:   *"I write a lot of mediocore CreepyPasta, best known (so far) for "[The Expressionless](http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Expressionless)" which has since gone viral on several forums"*

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt - Yes, the story is marked as _[OC](http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/Category:OC)_, which stands for _[Original Content](http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/Site_Rules/OC_and_User_Submissions#OC_Category)_. This means the story was not found on the internet, but written by the person who submitted it.

Comment: @Oliver_C: That is the ideal answer; please feel free to add it as such.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt - I'm not sure this question should stay open. Otherwise this might set a precedent for people to ask about _weird stories_ no one actually claims are true.

Comment: @Oliver_C: Perhaps what you are asking might be a good question for Meta?

Comment: @Oliver_C - I'm a huge fan of memes an urban legends so I'm fine with seeing more of them as well as there is evidence that they have managed to spread enough that you can find them with a quick Google search.

Comment: Creepypasta is not evidence of notability any more than Lord of the Rings is evidence of a notable belief that elves exist.

Comment: @Avi: Well, I know that **now**. :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**, this story is a good example of how an [urban legend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_legend) can spread and get reported as true. While there is the interesting coincidence that the Cedar Senai hospital in the story is similar [Cedars-Sinai Medical Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedars-Sinai_Medical_Center) in Los Angeles, California, the actual story itself is fictional and reported as such by the [author Ivysir](http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/User%3aIvysir):

> I write a lot of mediocore [sic] CreepyPasta, best known (so far) for "The
>   Expressionless" which has since gone viral on several forums, which
>   i'm [sic] eternally grateful for.

The [original story](http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Expressionless) can be found to contain the code "OC" which indicates "[Original Content](http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/User_Submissions)."